# What repository products are available for keeping track of web services?

Tags: esb

My organization is starting to take SOA seriously but before we jump in one of the components we seem to be missing is a rock solid repository for tracking these services across the enterprise.  Can anyone suggest a product that they have worked with?  If the product is also an ESB please mention that in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDDI functionality ships with Windows Server if all you need is a registry.

Comment: This was about the best answer I got, but my experience w/ UDDI has not been great thus far ;)

Answer (score 2):

You might like to take a look at IBM's WebSphere Service Registry and Repository. It does what you describe (with governance abilities as well), and integrates nicely with IBM's ESB products (although it not one itself).

Please feel free to get in touch if you want to ask any questions.

Disclaimer: I work for IBM as a WebSphere Consultant. However, I am not speaking for them in an official capacity.

Answer (score 1):

I also have worked for IBM and I would stay away from WSRR - it is buggy, immature, expensive and overly complex. I would not recommend it.